# "Cannot resolve symbol 'Cordform'" is shown in build.gradle for net.corda.plugins.Cordform

Tags: corda

although this not impact the build function, but still want to confirm with someone this is a correct behavior. I am using Corda V3.2, and in build.gradle, for this line of code:

```
task commonNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform, dependsOn: ['jar']) {
```

The Cordform is shown as gray color with an underline in IntelliJ, and when I hover on it, it shows "Cannot resolve symbol 'Cordform'". I checked sample CorDapps in Corda project, and they are using the same code, but the Cordform is not shown as error/warn. Does anyone can give an idea what might be wrong on my side? Thanks.

Comment: It's not usual behaviour, I've not seen that happen in any CorDapps before. Are you able to try this on someone else's machine just to confirm it's not something wrong with the IDE? Alternatively, if you could check this into a repo somewhere, I can run it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message is harmless. Unfortunately, IntelliJ's Gradle support is not perfect and it often highlights errors or issues with valid `build.gradle` files.